# Re-partitioning /home partition in CentOS

Tags: centos, partition, home, xfs

I have a CentOS 7 system with a /home partition that is too large. I wish to reduce its size but it's XFS so that's pretty much impossible. Since I don't have much user data anyway (only 1 user currently), is it possible to tar the entire partition data, copy it out, delete the partition, repartition it to, say, ext4, with a smaller size?

If so, what are the commands to do so?

Answer (score 2):

As this is not the root partition (`/`) you should be able to do this without losing data, if you login as the normal user, various files under your home directory are updated (from background email reading, surfing etc.). You don't want to lose emails that arrived between the backup and the restore).

The important thing to be able to repartition being is that you login either as root or as a user that doesn't have its home directory under `/home`. This is in order to be able to unmount `/home` without it being in use and repartition and reformat it.

Login in as root might not be possible, or at least not recommended, from the graphical interface (X, I'm not running CentOS 7 and cannot check). But graphical tools are probably more easy to use if you are less experienced in these ways. And if you are logged in and have a normal desktop you can also still use the internet to search for solutions if things go wrong. So in the following I will minimize reliance on using commandline tools.

You could move your existing user's `/home/XYZ` directory to e.g. `/home2/XYZ` (which is on the root partition), but there is probably too much data under that directory to do so. Therefore I recommend the following steps (for the `commands` you have to open a terminal):

1. create a new temporary user `xyz` with a home directory `/home2/xyz`
2. make sure this user can issue `sudo` commands
3. logout and login as this user (using the GUI, not via the `login:` prompt
4. unmount `/home` and remount it to make sure nothing is currently using it:

   ```
   sudo umount /home
   sudo mount /home
   ```
5. check that the backup medium is available, lets assume this is under `/mnt/USB01` (normally you check if the backup will fit, but you indicated 
   there is not much data, so I will assume it does).
6. use `tar` or `cpio` to backup from under `/home` (this is faster than copying individual files, and even should work if the backup medium is VFAT).

   ```
   sudo  tar --create --verbose --file=/mnt/USB01/homebup.tar.bz2 -C /home .
   ```
7. check that you can read back the file you just created:

   ```
   sudo tar tvf /mnt/USB01/homebup.tar.bz2
   ```
8. check on which partition `/home` is mounted, write the partition down (e.g. sdX2) and umount:

   ```
    mount | grep -f /home
    umount /home
   ```
9. comment out the entry for `/home` in `/etc/fstab`, you might have UUID instead of `sdX2`, you can lookup which UUID belongs to `sdX` by doing:

   ```
   ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep -F sdX2
   ```
10. repartition the drive `sdX` on which is the partition you found in the previous step, by deleting the `sdX2 partition and recreating it (if smaller you can create additional partitions now, or postpone that)
11. make your filesystem of choice on one of the newly created partitions (You can use`sdX2` again, but that partition will have a new UUID, so look it up)
12. edit `/etc/fstab` and make sure you can mount `/home` by doing:

    ```
    mount /home
    ```

    (by editing `/etc/fstab` and mounting this way you'll have the partition mounted on reboot).
13. (optional) reboot and make sure `/home` gets mounted
14. restore the data on `/home` with:

    ```
    sudo tar xvf /mnt/USB01/homebup.tar.bz2 -C /home
    ```
15. reboot and login normally
16. remove the temporary user account

Comment: This is quite a new setup, so I only have 1 user in /home, and there isn't much data in there at all. I've just checked, and I actually have enough space in my /root partition to house /home/user. I've copied the directory over to /root/home2/user and unmounted /home, but I'm not sure how to find out which partition it's on. fdisk shows the following information: 
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048  1953523711   976248832   8e  Linux LVM 
/etc/fstab shows "/dev/mapper/centos-home" for the /home entry.

Comment: Step 8 of the answer: You can check on which partition /home is by remounting it  and using `mount | fgrep /home`. Using `fdisk` is more guesswork as it doesn't know much about what is in its partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at something like [clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/).  With clonezilla on a small usb stick and somewhere to backup the data to (local or network), you could pretty much do exactly what you described - copy it out, delete the partition, re-partition it with both a different filesystem and smaller size, and then restore it.  Working directly with the partition image (usually the easiest option) won't work so well going from bigger to smaller, but you should still be able to make it work.  Check it out!

Comment: Hi, seems like clonezilla is a disk imaging software like Acronis that does bit-for-bit copy? Do I actually need this or would it be ok to just tar /home, copy it somewhere else, re-partition/re-size /home, copy the tar back and then untar it? Also, how would I actually re-partition it to a different filesystem and smaller size? Can I use something like gparted? Not sure if that works with XFS.